# Spring 3, Hibernate 4.1 Maven 3 Tutorial?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to configure my project to use Hibernate. I've created a simple webapp which uses Spring 3.2 and Maven 3. I've been trying to find a good tutorial about how to incorporate Hibernate 4.1 into this project, but can't seem to find one.

I need to figure out how to configure my spring-servlet.xml file and my persistence.xml file (I'd like to use the JPA specifications to run hibernate.)

The Hibernate documentation 
http://www.hibernate.org/docs 
seems utterly devoid of useful information.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/
looks like it would be useful. I tried following 2.B from that, but it still doesn't explain how to set up the persistence.xml, so ...

Anyone have any good recommendations?

Comment: Yes, JPA without Hibernate, rather use EclipseLink. Hibernate seems to be problematic the more I use it.

Comment: Why not to add the needed jars to pom.xml and then make the configuration files as in tutorials? ) Create a web-architecture project and move on.

Comment: the persistence.xml file should go inside your EAR's META-INF folder

Comment: I voted to close this issue because it seems like you are polling for "good" tutorials. Please improve this question by explaining a specific problem you are facing while attempting to configure your project.

Comment: I ended up "solving" the issue by throwing away my project, and starting from scratch using Spring's Java configuration instead of xml configuration. I used the spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.1 tutorial I mentioned to do so, and I got it all working with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/) a good tutorial to start over scratch with Hibernate Spring and Maven frameworks.

And there is other tutorials on the [same website](http://viralpatel.net/) just to discover.

Answer (score 1):

I used to implement this configuration (Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4) at this article:
[Migrating to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/)

With some little changes, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure...what are the exact issues that you are facing...but have you looked at this article http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_3_and_Hibernate_4_Example, it specifically talks about the Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 integration and sample code included in the article uses maven, so it may help and there is an example for annotation based integration too on that [site](http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_3_and_Annotation_Based_Hibernate_4_Example).